# Difference between search volume values by AdWords API and Keyword Planer GUI

Tags: google, google-ads, google-keyword-tool

In short, the problem is in the title. I realized, that search volume values, delivered by querying AdWords API are different (higher) than values shown by Keyword Planer GUI of Google Ads.

Language and location settings checked twice - they are not the cause. Aggregation should be not a cause too - Keyword Planer GUI shows values for each month of the last year, but no monthly value is as high as AdWords API is giving out.

Any thoughts about the difference?

Answer (score 1):

As it often happens with issues i experience, immediately after i post an issue into StackExchange, i get the solution by myself, independently of the time i invested into finding solution before posting:) Well here is it:

The data discrepancy between AdWords API and Keyword Planner GUI was caused in my case by two factors:

1. Missed setting. The setting `NetworkSetting` wasn't explizitely declared as `targetGoogleSearch`. The API uses per default the setting `targetSearchNetwork`.
2. Previous API version (20180**6** or even earlier - don't realized exactly) queried historical metrics per default within the timeframe of **24** month. The current version (20180**9**) queries get historical metrics from within **12** months.

That is why numbers by AdWords API were higher than those by Keyword Planner GUI.